# Bootstrap carousel arrows move when position set to relative

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, position, carousel

I've been having trouble displaying the caption text on my bootstrap carousel when the position of.carousel-caption is absolute.  When the css is absolute the text moves up, over my carousel image.

This problem is only solved when the position is changed to relative.  However, when this happens, the arrows change position, moving down below the page, as do the 'li' circular images.

I want to make sure my carousel caption remains visible, but have the arrows and circular carousel icons remain in the same place.

Here is some of my CSS code:

```
   .carousel-inner> .item> img {
height:110px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

.carousel-caption{
  max-width:550px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-left:120px;
  position:relative;
}

.carousel-caption p{
  font-size: 25px;
  color:black;
  text-shadow:none;
}

.carousel-indicators{
  bottom:-300px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since positioning the image, we need to help out the the caption.
 Keep absolute for position.

```
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
position : absolute
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but, as I said, when the position is absolute, the text moves over the carousel image and therefore doesn't work.